# Taking main argument

Tags: c, command-line-arguments, program-entry-point, cs50, argv

I have a problem with my code. I would like to know what the "variation" value is. But it always gives me extremely high or negative values. So when I type in terminal for example ./NAME 3 I end up with another number. How can i fix it?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>


int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    int variation =  (int)argv[1];
    if (argc == 2)
    {

        printf("%i\n", variation);

        return 0;
    }

    else
    {
        return 1;
    }

}
```

Comment: you need a string to number converter and c does not have any type named `string`

Comment: https://cs50.stackexchange.com/

Comment: For better or worse, the `cs50.h` header provides `typedef char *string;` — and people taking the CS50 course can't really be expected to understand the niceties of "C does not have a type `string`" since the C they're encouraged to work with does have the type `string`.

Comment: for heaven's sake, there is no `%i` , no type '`string`'... why does CS50, such a reputed course, insult C like this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Note: `C` does not have builtin `string` type. What `C` has is `character array`]

This is a very easy to solve problem. Here's the code given, it uses `stdlib`'s builtin `atoi` function to convert `string` to `int`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    if (argc == 2) {
    
        char *var_str = argv[1];
        
        int variation = atoi(var_str);

        printf("variation: %d\n", variation);
    
    }
    else if (argc < 2) {
    
        printf("no agrument provided.\n");

    } else {

        printf("only one argument was expected. %d provided.\n", argc);
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

**Update (A more secure version using `strtol`):**

As `strtol` is a better function to convert `string` to `long int`, than `atoi`, because of it's error detecting `utility`, it's better to use `strtol` in this regard. This practice is heavily enforced by user `@klutt`. I would like to thank her/him for advising me to include the code using `strtol` too. It is given below:

```c
// a more secure version

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    if (argc == 2) {
        char *var_str = argv[1];

        char *text = NULL;
        int base = 10; // default base

        errno = 0; // intializing errno

        long int variation = 0;
        variation = strtol(var_str, &text, base);

        // now on to error detection
        // full error trace
        if (var_str == text) {
            printf ("error: no number found\n");

        } else if (errno == ERANGE && variation == LONG_MIN) {
            printf ("error: underflow\n");

        } else if (errno == ERANGE && variation == LONG_MAX) {
            printf ("error: overflow\n");

        } else if (errno != 0 && variation == 0) {
            printf ("error: unknown error\n");

        } else if (errno == 0 && var_str && !*text) {
            printf ("variation: %ld\n", variation);

        } else if (errno == 0 && var_str && *text != 0) {
            printf ("variation: %d, but some text included: %s\n", variation, text);
        }

    } else if (argc < 2) {
    
        printf("no agrument provided.\n");

    } else {

        printf("only one argument was expected. %d provided.\n", argc);
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

If you have any questions, ask me in comment...

Comment: Thanks man. This will function as long as variation is not 0, right? I say for atoi()

Comment: Advocate `strtol` instead. `atoi` cannot be error checked.

Comment: @Danielvelin, it'll function as long as `variation` is `integer`, i.e. when `variation` is `negative`, it'll function, when `variation` is `0`, it'll function, when `variation` is `positive`, it'll function...

Comment: @reyad.Thanks again

Comment: `var_str` is redundant

Comment: @klutt, i guess, OP is passing only one parameter `./Name 3`. So, it won't be a problem in this case, if it has a restricted usecase...but otherwise, you're right `strtol` better to use...

Comment: @reyad Safe functions are always preferable to non-safe unless you can guarantee that the input is safe, so `strtol` would be the default function to use. Especially in a case like this where it's about user input, which is unreliable by definition. What if the user passes `./Name hello` or `./Name 3.4` or `./Name 2147483648`? (The last one is 1 bigger than `INT_MAX`)

Comment: @reyad What I'm saying is that if you have to pick only one function to learn, then it should be `strtol` instead of `atoi` :)

Comment: @klutt, I completely agree with you in all cases, but this: `strtol` returns `long int`, which in most machine is `4 byte`, same as `integer`. So, it's much not a help `./Name 2147483648` in this case. But, all other cases I agree...

Comment: @klutt, I also agree with your second point...One of the reason, I've provided `atoi`, so that I can make OP[(s)he seems like a newbie] easily understand that, what we need here is to convert 'string' to 'number', that's all. `strtol` uses three params(with a base), so, `atoi` seems easier and understantable to deliver for a `newbie`. If (s)he sticks around with, of course (s)he'll start using `strtol`. But, in this case, I though, it is better to deliver the understandings simply....I hope I make it clear to you...

Comment: @reyad You can check if the conversion has succeeded with `if(errno == ERANGE)`. For your second point, my opinion is that the dangers in C is too often hidden from newbies. If you want a language where everything is safe, don't pick C. If you pick C, you need to learn about the dangers.

Comment: @klutt, you'll only get stronger by facing danger, if that doesn't kill you...:P...jokes apart, I will edit my answer...and also include the secure version...I hope you could agree to that...

Comment: @reyad Hehehe, sure. Well, it's just that if you teach beginners unsafe methods, they will soon have some weird undefined behavior, and then they post a new question where the answer is how to use the safe methods that can be error checked. :)

Comment: @klutt, I've included the code with `strtol`, pls have a look...tell me if i can improve it in some way...